# updating records in derby database not working

Tags: java, sql, derby

Can someone help me, the problem is when I run this code I keep getting this Syntax error: Encountered "[" at line 1, column 24 . BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 44 seconds)
I can't see where I made a mistake in the code

```
String id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the Employess ID", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

                String fname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Employess First NAME", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String sname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Employess Surname NAME", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String pss = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the Employess PPS Number", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);   
                String cnum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please ente thr Employess Contact Number", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String address  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Employess  Address", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String dep = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Employess Deparment ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String sal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Employess  salary", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, id + sname +  "Records have been entered ");

       try{

    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost/ee ";
    String uName = "aa";
    String uPass = "bb";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
//Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host);
//Customer Lookup by Last Name

//SQL

String sql = "UPDATE emp SET  fname = [?],sname = [?],pss = [?],cnum = [?],address = [?],dep = [?],sal =[?] where id = [?]";



prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);


    prest.setString(1,id);
    prest.setString(2,fname);
    prest.setString(3,sname);
    prest.setString(4,pss);
    prest.setString(5,cnum);
    prest.setString(6,address);
    prest.setString(7,dep);
    prest.setString(8,sal);
    prest.executeUpdate();


    }
    catch (SQLException err) {

    System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
    }
                }

    }
```

Comment: Get rid of the `[]` those are invalid in SQL. **only** the `?` is used for a placeholder

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name  thanks but  now I am getting   Syntax error: Encountered  "where" line 1  column 89

Comment: Don't forget to check the return code of `executeUpdate`. Perhaps there are no records with that ID.

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton    I know that there is a record with a Id of 333, but if I try to update that record it dose not to anything to that record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parameter placeholder (`?`) should always immediately follow the equal sign without delimiters of any kind:

```java
String sql = "UPDATE emp SET fname=?, sname=?, pss=?, cnum=?, address=?, dep=?, sal=? WHERE id=?";
```

or

```java
String sql = "UPDATE emp SET fname = ?, sname = ?, pss = ?, cnum = ?, address = ?, dep = ?, sal = ? WHERE id = ?";
```

Comment: The whitespace is no problem `fname = ? , sname = ? ` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Quite true. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: @Gord Thompson                              
thanks that got rid of that error  but now it doesn't seem to update

Comment: @ryan - It looks like you are declaring the parameter values in the wrong order. They should be declared in the exact same order that they appear in the command text. (Hint: `id` should be the last parameter value assigned, not the first.)